# Almost the same statements, but different value

Tags: java, return, backtracking

I'm working on a classic DP question, Count Subset Sum.

The problem statement is as follows if you are not sure about the problem:
Given a set of positive numbers, find the total number of subsets whose sum is equal to a given number ‘S’.

I'm trying to work solve it with backtracking approach.

Assume the given array is `[1, 1, 2, 3]` and the `sum` is 4, so the expected result is `3`
The weird thing is the code blow works fine, and it generates the correct result.

```java
  private int backtrack2(int[] nums, int sum) {
    int[] count = new int[1];
    backtrack2Helper(nums, sum, count, 0);
    return count[0];
  }

  private int backtrack2Helper(int[] nums, int sum, int[] count, int pos) {
    if (0 == sum) return 1;
    if (pos == nums.length) return 0;

    for (int i = pos; i < nums.length; ++i) {
      if (sum - nums[i] >= 0) {
        int temp = backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1);
        count[0] += temp;
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

However, the code below can not generate the correct result:

```java
  private int backtrack2(int[] nums, int sum) {
    int[] count = new int[1];
    backtrack2Helper(nums, sum, count, 0);
    return count[0];
  }

  private int backtrack2Helper(int[] nums, int sum, int[] count, int pos) {
    if (0 == sum) return 1;
    if (pos == nums.length) return 0;

    for (int i = pos; i < nums.length; ++i) {
      if (sum - nums[i] >= 0) {
        count[0] += backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1);
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

The only difference is the `if` statement part in the helper function.

```java
int temp = backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1);
count[0] += temp;
```

and

```java
count[0] += backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1);
```

should be equivalent, right?

But the second one does not work correctly.
I was really confused and I debugged it step by step, finding that when the method in the second approach hit the return statement at last, `count[0]` was not added by the returned 0, but set to 0.

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference results from the fact that `backtrack2Helper()` changes `count[0]`.

Suppose, for example, that `backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1)` changes that value of `count[0]` from `0` to `1` and returns `1`.

In one snippet you are adding the changed value of `count[0]` to the value returned by the recursive call:

```
int temp = backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1); // == 1
count[0] += temp; // == 1 + 1 == 2
```

But in the other snippet you are adding the original value of `count[0]` to the value returned by the recursive call:

```
count[0] += backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], count, i + 1); // == 0 + 1 == 1
```

EDIT:

You can write a more elegant solution without the `count[]` array:

```
private static int backtrack2(int[] nums, int sum) {
    return backtrack2Helper(nums, sum, 0);
}

private static int backtrack2Helper(int[] nums, int sum, int pos) {
    if (0 == sum)
        return 1;
    if (pos == nums.length)
        return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = pos; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        if (sum - nums[i] >= 0) {
            count += backtrack2Helper(nums, sum - nums[i], i + 1);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

EDIT:

To improve the explanation regarding the difference of the two snippets, here's a simpler code that produces the same behavior:

```
int method2 (int[] arr)
{
   arr[0] = 5;
   return 0; 
}
```

First snippet:

```
void method1 ()
{
    int[] arr = new int[1]; // arr[0] is 0
    int temp = method2 (arr); // temp is assigned 0, arr[0] is changed to 5 by method2
    arr[0] += temp // arr[0] = arr[0] + temp == 5 + 0 == 5
}
```

Second snippet:

```
void method1 ()
{
    int[] arr = new int[1]; // arr[0] is 0
    arr[0] += method2 (arr); // arr[0] = arr[0] + method2 (arr) == 0 + 0 == 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So, is it because ```count[]``` is the parameter of the method? If so, it should work correctly if I set ```count``` as a global variable.

Comment: @AU_yzy0050 making count a global variable would make no difference, assuming `backtrack2Helper()` would still change `count[0]`

Comment: My understanding is not correct. Simply setting ```count``` as a global variable does not work.

Comment: @AU_yzy0050 you can eliminate the `count[]` array entirely. See edit

Comment: Hey, @Eran, thanks for your edit. I've studied it and understood it. But I'm still confused about your answer about my original question. Why is ```count[0]``` in the first one changed, while the second one not changed? Please educate me on this issue.

Comment: @AU_yzy0050 it is changed in both cases, but not in the same way. when you write `count[0] += backtrack2Helper()`, it's equivalent to `count[0] = count[0] + backtrack2Helper();` Now, if `backtrack2Helper()` changes the value of `count[0]`. that change will be lost, since that statement adds the value of `count[0]` (prior to executing `backtrack2Helper()`) to the value returned by `backtrack2Helper()`. When you use the `temp` variable, you execute `backtrack2Helper()` before the `count[0]+=` statement, so this time you are adding `backtrack2Helper()` to the modified value of `count[0]`.

Comment: thank you. Finally, I understand what's going on in there.